How do upload images to Artifactory with layers larger than 2GB when using an external database
We are currently encountering issues with our Artifactory installation. Our instance is running in Kubernetes, and initially, we had it running with regular PVCs and no problems. However, when we attempted to migrate it to SQL Server as an external database, we encountered problems with images having layers larger than 2 GB. The error received was:

error pushing image: failed to push to destination repo.dummy.com/docker/...: PATCH https://repo.dummy.com/v2/...: : org.jfrog.storage.binstore.exceptions.BinaryDbException: Could not insert Stream due to:Attempting to grow LOB beyond maximum allowed size of 2147483647 bytes.

We suspected that this might be a limitation of SQL Server, so we decided to migrate JFrog to PostgreSQL as an external database. However, we encountered similar issues with large layers in images, resulting in these errors:
Docker Push Error:

error pushing image: failed to push to destination repo.dummy.com/docker/...: PATCH https://repo.dummy.com/v2/...: : org.jfrog.storage.binstore.exceptions.BinaryDbException: Could not insert Stream due to:Object is too large to send over the protocol.

Artifactory Logs:
2024-06-11T13:15:35.386Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [1d605e8db503fbbf] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:52] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - org.jfrog.storage.binstore.exceptions.BinaryDbException: Could not insert Stream due to:Object is too large to send over the protocol.

The expected behavior is that we should be able to upload images with larger layer sizes, exceeding 2 GB, while also utilizing an external database.

I dunno about postgre but you won't be able to do this in sql server. why not store the files on disk and just store the paths in the db

Databases really aren't the ideal place to store files. Store the files in a file system, and store the path (and any additional meta data you need) in the database. Then, when someone wants a specific file, grab the path from the database, and have the application open the file from said path.

I consider storing files in a database a "Taco Bell Solution".   Seems like a good idea at the time, but you'll end up regretting it.  :)

I also like how this question says: "we had a system without problem, but then for some reason we created problems for us".

You could use pg_largeobject to store files up to 4TB in size. However, I would like to advice you to store a file on a file system, that's the natural location for an object like that.

Of course it's a limitation of SQL Server. The varbinary(max) data type has a maximum storage of 2^31-1 bytes.
